# enum(field) is not working in a partition relatedGoals

Tags: server, graphql, backend, apollo

I need help resolving the issue with GraphQL. The problem is that the enum(field) is not working in a partition `relatedGoals`

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql

  type Goal {
    id: ID!
    goalName: String!
    categories: Categories!
    description: String!
    tag: String!
    relatedGoals: RelatedGoals!
    deadline: String!
    keepReminding: Boolean!
    taskGoal: [GoalTask]
  }

  type GoalTask {
    id: ID!
    goalsId: ID!
    taskName: String!
    taskDescription: String!
    taskTime: String
  }

  input CreateGoalInput {
    goalName: String!
    categories: Categories!
    description: String!
    tag: String!
    relatedGoals: RelatedGoals!
    deadline: String!
    keepReminding: Boolean!
    taskGoal: [CreateGoalTaskInput!]!
  }

  input CreateGoalTaskInput {
    taskName: String!
    taskDescription: String!
    taskTime: String
  }

  enum Categories {
    PERSONAL
    PROFESSIONAL
    ACADEMIC
  }

  enum RelatedGoals {
    OFFENSIVE_GOAL
    DEFENSIVE_GOAL
  }


  input EditGoalInput {
    goalName: String!
    categories: Categories!
    description: String!
    tag: String!
    relatedGoals: RelatedGoals!
    deadline: String
    keepReminding: Boolean!
    taskGoal: [EditGoalTaskInput]
  }

  input EditGoalTaskInput {
    id: ID!
    taskName: String!
    taskDescription: String!
    taskTime: String!
  }


  type Mutation {
    # Create a new goal for a student with the provided input
    createGoal(studentId: ID!, input: CreateGoalInput!): Goal!
  },
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

The error from apollo-client is

```
"Error creating Goal:
invalid input value for enum \"enum_Goals_relatedGoals\": \"OFFENSIVE_GOAL\"",
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're calling the mutation from the client? One guess is that you didn't quote `"OFFENSIVE_GOAL"` - it may be an enum but it still needs a string.

Comment: "Now I know where the problem is, it's in the magration file, where I can't change the field name. It should stay as I named it in the beginning. Does this mean it's broken or because I downloaded a new version in postgresql, but I just downloaded it, and didn't convert it," Haven't I worked on it yet?"

Comment: I suggest rewording the question to take this into account. Or close this one and open a new one with the actual problem.